# Bad pic quality from Photoshop export on my Website

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, resolution

Despite that the fact that I saved it with a resolution enough to be double as big.
[image]

The curve here has an awful quality with white resins. Only slightly visible here, but how can I change that??

Comment: Don't make the Image too big. If its gets scaled down more than 50% by the Browser Google will penalise(Decrease your SEO rating) you for that.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really see the problem from the screenshot that you attached, however there are a few things to consider:

1. The format and quality level you are exporting the image at. When exporting from PS you'll get various settings and you want to make sure that the highest possible quality is selected.
2. As SZCZERZO said, browsers are not as good at resizing images as Photoshop, so you'll want to give it the EXACT size it has in the browser for the best results.
3. If you are using a high dpi screen (i.e. a retina macbook), your site will need a script to recognise retina graphics (such as retina.js) and you will need to have two versions of the image, one at the exact size it will be on the site, and one at exactly double that size.

If none of these work, you could also copy and paste that shape into Illustrator (using the white arrow key) then exporting it as an SVG.

Perhaps I'd be able to help more if you posted a link to the site and the original graphic.

Answer (score -1):

Don't export with doubled resolution. When you give the browser bigger image it gets shrinked to smaller size. And the browser usually is not as good as photoshop in recalculating. 
So if you want a 1440x1200px picture stay with 72 or 96 px/inch.